# bignum too big to convert into `long' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crc

i am getting this error while executing below code

```
@crc=0xFFFFFFFF  
@index=0

7.times { |n| 
@index+=@crc**@a[n]
@crc=@crc >> 8
puts @crc
**@crc=@crc**@reverse_crc[@index]** - this is the line i am getting above error while execute
puts @crc
}
```

any one have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to operate on ruby Integer classes:

```
@crc = Integer(@crc ** @reverse_crc[Integer(@index)])
```

When Integer is too big for a Fixnum, it is automatically converted into a Bignum.